# How do I POST form data using Fetch and React?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, jsx

I am using react and fetch to submit a post request to my local json server. The goal is to submit a "comment" on a form and add that to the json server. My json file doesn't appear to be updating. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './commentform.css';

class CommentForm extends Component {

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('submitted')
    }
            

    render(){
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/comments', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log(response)
                return response.json()
                })
        return (
            <div>
            <h1>What is your favorite breed?</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>Answer: </label><br/>
                    <textarea type="text" name="body"/><br/>
                    <input type="submit"/>
                </form>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CommentForm
```

Comment: You're not handling textarea text change and setting the value to state. And also, the fetch must be inside handleSubmit not in render function.

Answer (score 1):

**I think we have a lot of problems on this.**

**Before anything:**
You should not put your fetch API inside the render() method like that, you want to POST the data when the user submits the form, right? That is not happening right now, let me help you with that.

**Ok, let's go:**
Firstly, [this React tutorial is about adding State to a React Class Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class). Now that you've seen how to do it on the right way, we see that you don't have a constructor to initialize your state, then you'd have to do something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = { text: "" }
}
```

and now you have a state object with a prop called text "" as initial value.

**Next:**
You want to change this state with the typed data on the textarea, right? So you need something to trigger this action of typing. React provides us with the "onChange" event, to assign the typed data to the state you would need to do something like this:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <label>Answer: </label><br/>
  <textarea type="text" name="body" onChange={(e) => this.setState({ text: e.target.value })}/><br/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

And now you're correctly assigning the typed data to your state.

**Almost finishing:**
You want to POST the data that is on the state when the user clicks on "submit", which is binded to call "handleSubmit", which actually does nothing but log "submitted". You want to put the fetch API inside this function, making it [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). You should do something like this:

```
handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('Submitting form')
  fetch('http://localhost:3001/comments', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: this.state.text
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
    return response.json()
  })
  console.log('Form submitted.')
}
```

And now you're POSTing your data when user actually clicks on the submit button.

**Just a quick warning:**
You did not provide enough code to see how your local json server is receiving your request body so you should check if the way that I provided the data fits to you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I applied your code but still can't seem to get the comment to post. This is what I have in my db.json file 
{
    "comments": [
        
    ]
}

Comment: I changed my db.json file to the following

Comment: {
    "comments": [
      { 
        "id": 1, 
        "body": "some comment" 
    }
]
}

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The biggest issue is that you are attempting to make the POST request from within the `render` lifecycle method, which is very anti-pattern in React. It should be done in a handler or regular lifecycle method, like `componentDidUpdate`.

When you submit the form you are also sending the entire `state` object... but you never update this.

## Solution

### Option 1

Keep the uncontrolled inputs and access the form field in the submit handler.

```
class CommentForm extends Component {
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submitted");

    const body = e.target.body.value;

    fetch("http://localhost:3001/comments", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json(); // do something with response JSON
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>What is your favorite breed?</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>Answer: </label>
          <br />
          <textarea type="text" name="body" />
          <br />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### Option 2

Convert to fully controlled inputs and access the state in the submit handler. You'll need to add a `value` prop and an `onChange` handler to the textarea to update local state.

```
class CommentForm extends Component {
  state = {
    body: '',
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submitted");

    const { body } = this.state;

    fetch("http://localhost:3001/comments", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { body } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>What is your favorite breed?</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>Answer: </label>
          <br />
          <textarea
            type="text"
            name="body"
            value={body}
            onChange={e => this.setState({
              body: e.target.value
            })}
          />
          <br />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Drew- thank you for this!! I tried both options and still can't get my JSON server to receive the data. Any ideas?

Comment: Getting error CommentForm.js:11 POST http://localhost:3000/comments 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Port 3000 is usually the default port your React app runs on. Your code is pointed to port 3001 for your server. Are you sure you've all the correct ports?

Comment: So I changed it to the proper port after I used your code anyway but still doesn't seem to work. Any other ideas why it wouldn't be working?

Comment: @megcho Sorry, I was on vacation. We do need a bit more detail and context, just saying it isn't working isn't very helpful. Have you narrowed down what isn't working? Your app is making a POST request, so have you verified via the network tab that the request is being made, and with the correct request body? Is your server receiving the request? If so, how is it being handled there? What is the request disposition (i.e. response status, 200 OK, 404, etc...)? We've yet to figure out if this is a front or backend issue.